# TideSDK php connect via ssh

Tags: php, ssh, tidesdk

Are there any possibilities to connect to server via ssh using php in tidesdk.
I'm trying to use

```
$session = ssh2_connect($server, 22);
```

But an error occurred

```
Fatal error - Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

The fact that it's pure-PHP means it's ultra-portable. Unlike the libssh2 extension you're currently trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the SSH2 extension?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Comment: For sure it is installed in my system, but not in tidesdk. I can execute same script in browser without any errors.